# gscatter help required for matlab

Tags: statistics, matlab

I am new to the Stats Package in MATLAB and am trying to make a scatter plot between vectors A and B (so A vs B), but I want to show A values in 1 color and B values in another color.

e.g. A = [1 2 3 4];
     B = [1.2 2.2 3.2 4.2];

I don't want to use "scatter" and "hold on" etc. and want to learn about grouping data to use in "gscatter". I tried to read the help, the could not understand it. So a small example will be very useful (with comments).

Thanks!

Comment: Independetly of MATLAB, for a scatter on a cartesian plane, you need 2d coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to figure out your coordinates. If you say you want to plot `A`vs `B`that gives you 4 pairs - and `A`would equal `X`in such a plot, just as `B` would equal `Y`.
This, however, raises the question of how to group them to get individual colors. It makes no sense to say, "I want `A` to be red and `B` to be blue" - because they are part of the same symbol. 
Therefore, either `A` and `B` both have to be `Y`, which raises questions about what `X` should be, or the grouping has to be different.
Here's an explanation on how [`gscatter`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gscatter.html) works, you can then figure out the grouping:

```
gscatter(A,B,group,CLR,SYM);
```

First, `CLR` is a `string` variable containing colors and `SYM` is a `string` variable containing symbols. The `length` of `CLR` and `SYM` has to correspond to the different elements in `group`.
`group` is a [`grouping variable`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/grouping-variables.html). These are very flexible.
Let's look at an easy example:
Assume, that the first two pairs of `A` and `B` are a group, as well as the second. We can then specify `group` as:

```
group = [0 0 1 1];
```

With

```
CLR = 'rb';
SYM = 'xo';

gscatter(A,B,group,CLR,SYM);
```

Will produce a plot that has two data sets, one consisting of red x-es and the other of blue circles.

Comment: Thanks Schorsch. I think 'grouping variables' is my problem. I am modeler, not a statistician and do not understand very well how this is done in MATLAB. Looking at the documentation example,         load discrim
gscatter(ratings(:,1),ratings(:,2),group,'br','xo');                                I see that "group" variable in workspace is [length(ratings) * 1] column vector with 1s and 2s. I don't understand how that divides 2 columns in different groups.

Comment: @AyeshaKalra : Completely rewrote my answer. Please comment if you need additional information.

Comment: @AyeshaKalra From wikipedia: "*Statistics is the study of the collection, organization, analysis, interpretation and presentation of data. It deals with all aspects of data, including the planning of data collection in terms of the design of surveys and experiments*." Clearly, a statistician is a modeler. Now, if you are a modeler but not a statistician, and you're trying to use a statistician's tools, what type of modeler are you?

Comment: @AyeshaKalra if this answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it. Or comment if you need additional clarification.

Comment: Thanks Schorsch. This helped me understand better.